# how to know curl file called via cli or apache2handler

Tags: php, curl, command-line-interface

I have **call-cli.php**

I am executing it via command line.

> code of call-cli.php

```
echo "File 1 ".php_sapi_name(); // returns cli
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost/curltest/step1.php?productId=12");
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

> code of step1.php

```
echo " step1 ".php_sapi_name(); // returns apache2handler
if(php_sapi_name()==='cli') {
    // To do execute code regarding cli
}
if(php_sapi_name()==='apache2handler') {
    // To do execute code regarding apache2handler
}
```

When ADMIN run step1.php via browser it should execute apache2handler code and for cli the diff one.
I am getting **productId** from **call-cli.php**. So I need to invoke curl from **call-cli.php**
So I want to know is there any way to find curl called via cli file returns cli instead of apache2handler or any other suggestion?

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you actually ask. But I understand that you reer t the second result in `step1` which is unexpected for you?Why should that return `cli`? It has been called via an http request by curl, that request certainly is _not_ executed on `cli`... You'd have to use something like `exec()` for that instead of `curl()`...

Comment: @arkascha thanks got your point, hope updated question is clear.

Comment: You are using the wrong strategy to differ between the two different calls, since both are executed in the same environment. What you _can_ do instead is one of these two options: 1. add a request argument to the `curl` call which allows to differ on the receiving side or use http request headers which can also be examined on the requested side.

Comment: yes  @arkascha I thought same solution but I was worried about security point so moved to cli...Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just have two different files? One for cli usage, and one for ADMIN web usage?

Comment: @Nothing against CLI usage, it definitely does make sense in some situations. I did not suggest not to use it, in contrary.

Answer (score 0):

No, as Curl opens the `step1.php` file like a browser via HTTP which is handled by the web server. Apache in this case, therefore it's `apache2handler`.

But PHP scripts will only output `cli` if executed from a terminal.

Comment: yes I know but for productId I need to invoke it from call-cli.php. hope updated question is clear.

Answer (score 0):

The curl call in `call-cli.php` is calling curl via cli, but since you are echoing the result of `step1.php`, which is served via Apache, you are seeing `apache2handler` in your code.

If you call `step1.php` via command line (e.g. `php step1.php`), you will see that it also returns `cli`.

Not sure what you are trying to achieve, so please clarify your questions.

Comment: Thank @Niraj Shah  I know but for productId I need to invoke it from call-cli.php. hope updated question is clear.

Comment: Just a detail, but: the url()` call in `call-cli.php` is _not_ done via CLI to the `cURL` executable! It is an internal function call to the `cURL` extension library loaded into php.